# How to split the time component of a datetime stamp?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Is it possible to split up the time part of a datetime string into the hours, minutes and seconds, so that i have a single numerical value for each field?  Ideally on retrieval from a mysql database.

I have looked about on the site and there appears to be an abundance of advice on how to split the date and time parts but none concerning my specific question.  Many thanks in advance.

P.S I would be selecting the datetime from a mysql database using PHP.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Now tell us what have you tried?

Comment: Nothing as of yet.  I had no idea how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this directly in sql:

```
SELECT HOUR( timestamp_field ) AS HOUR, 
       MINUTE( timestamp_field ) AS MINUTE, 
       SECOND( timestamp_field ) AS SECOND
FROM some_table
```

Or if you want to do it in php after executing the query

```
$datetime = "1997-12-31 23:59:59";
$parsed = date_parse($datetime);
```

Which will look like

```
Array
(
[year] => 1997
[month] => 12
[day] => 31 
[hour] => 23
[minute] => 59
[second] => 59
[fraction] => 0.5
[warning_count] => 0
[warnings] => Array()
[error_count] => 0
[errors] => Array()
[is_localtime] => 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<?php
$timestamp = 1359837241;
$hour = date('H', $timestamp);
$minute = date('i', $timestamp);
$second = date('s', $timestamp);
echo $hour . '<br>';
echo $minute . '<br>';
echo $second . '<br>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

With blow code You Can Convert DateTime to TimeStamp

```
$date = new DateTime("1897-04-21 22:55:19");
$TimeStamp=$date->getTimestamp();
```

And With **date()** Function You Can Split TimeStamp To Year,Min,Sec

```
echo date("H",$TimeStamp);
.
.
.
```

For more info see [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then this should do:

```
<?php
    $timeStamp = '2012-10-23 13:35:20';
    $timeStampSplode = explode( ' ', $timeStamp );

    $head = $timeStampSplode[0];
    $tail = $timeStampSplode[1];

    $headSplode = explode( '-', $head );
    $tailSplode = explode( ':', $tail );

    $year = $headSplode[0];
    $month = $headSplode[1];
    $date = $headSplode[2];

    $hour = $tailSplode[0];
    $minute = $tailSplode[1];
    $second = $tailSplode[2];

    echo "Year: ". $year. "<br />";
    echo "month: ". $month. "<br />";
    echo "date: ". $date. "<br />";
    echo "hour: ". $hour. "<br />";
    echo "minute: ". $minute. "<br />";
    echo "second: ". $second. "<br />";
?>
```

And It's no problem to use $timeStamp as a value fetched from the database.